# Most efficient way to do this select in JPA 2?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jpa-2.0

I have an `Entity` that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Relationship
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Basic
    private UUID from;

    @Basic
    private UUID to;
}
```

Now I can have arbitrary levels of indirection here like so:

```
final Relationship r0 = new Relationship(a,b);
final Relationship r1 = new Relationship(b,c);
final Relationship r2 = new Relationship(c,d);
final Relationship rN = new Relationship(d,e);
```

Now what I want to find out as efficiently as possible is given `a` give me back `e` where `rN` is `N` level deep.

If I was writing regular `SQL` I would do something like the follow pseudo code :

```
SELECT r.to 
FROM relationship r
WHERE r.from = 'a' AND
      r.to NOT IN ( SELECT r.from FROM relationship r)
```

The only thing I can find online is references to passing in a `List` as a parameter to a `Criteria.Builder.In` but I don't have the list, I need to use a sub-select as the list?

Also this is using the `Datastore` in Google App Engine, and it is restricted on some things that it supports via JPA 2.

Am I going to have to resort to the low level `Datastore` API?

Answer (score 0):

In the datastore, there's no way to issue a single query to get 'e' from 'a'.  In fact the only way to get e, is to individually query each Relationship linearly, so you'll need to do four queries.

You can pass in a list as a parameter, but that's only for an `IN` query.  `NOT IN` queries are not available, and neither are `JOIN`s.

(Aside: you could use a combination of the `from` and `to` properties to create a key, in which case you could just fetch the entity instead of query).

Usually, the GAE datastore version of doing things is to denormalize, ie write extra data that will enable your queries.  (This is a pain, because it also means that when you update an entity, you need to be careful to update the denormalized data as well, and it can be hard to synchronize this - It's designed for web type traffic where reads occur much more frequently than writes.)

This is a potential solution:

```
@Entity
public class Relationship
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Basic
    private UUID from;

    @Basic
    private UUID to;

    @ElementCollection
    private Collection<UUID> reachable;
}
```

In this case you would simply query

```
WHERE from = 'a' and reachable = 'e'
```

Comment: I have researched the `@ElementCollection` and I don't see how that helps me unless I do away with the `to` attribute and just store a list of the alias `UUID` on a single `Entity` then I have the opposite problem, I have to find everything in reverse if one of up-stream aliases change ...

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Surprisingly enough this recursive method doesn't error out with a StackOverflow even with 1000 levels of indirection, at least not on my local development server.

```
public UUID resolve(@Nonnull final UUID uuid)
{
    final EntityManager em = EMF.TRANSACTIONS_OPTIONAL.createEntityManager();
    try
    {
        final String qs = String.format("SELECT FROM %s a WHERE a.from = :from ", Alias.class.getName());
        final TypedQuery<Alias> q = em.createQuery(qs, Alias.class);
        q.setParameter("from", uuid);
        final Alias r;
        try
        {
            r = q.getSingleResult();
            final Key tok = KeyFactory.createKey(Alias.class.getSimpleName(), r.getTo().toString());
            if (em.find(Alias.class, tok) == null)
            {
                return r.getTo();
            }
            else
            {
                return this.resolve(r.getTo());
            }
        }
        catch (final NoResultException e)
        {
            /* this is expected when there are no more aliases */
            return uuid;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

*The stress test code I had is timing out on the actual GAE Service, but I am not worried about it, I won't be creating more than one level of indirection at a time in practice. And there won't be more than a handful of indirections either, and it will all get hoisted up into `Memcache` in the final version anyway.*